# How to use sqlite3.exe to create database from exported .sql script

Tags: sqlite

Trying to convert an SqlCe database to SQLite, I export it to a `.sql` file. Now how would I use `sqlite.exe` to create a database from this `.sql` file?

Where to put the `sql3.exe` file?
What command syntax to use, in cmd prompt or in the `sqlite.exe` shell?

Answer (score 9):

Use following command line:

```
sqlite3 -init dump.sql newsqlite.db ""
```

It will create new SQLite database file `newsqlite.db` by executing statements from `dump.sql`. Empty string `""` is needed for sqlite3 to quit automatically.

If `newsqlite.db` file already existed with some data, import may fail unless you use `IF NOT EXISTS` for all table and index creation statements.

Comment: Cheers! Still, cmd prompt gives me the message : `-- Loading resources from script.sql` then `Error: incomplete SQL: |-` (| beeing a rectangle), while sqlite3.exe shell for the same command gives me just a new line `...>`  Either way not much of an error message, no line number, no nothing. Is that typical?

Comment: For this to work, your `script.sql` must be valid - it clearly isn't. I'd suggest to debug your script line by line. In windows, you should install [SQLite Expert Personal](http://www.sqliteexpert.com) and use this GUI to carefully debug your script - there is something wrong in it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint with the empty string!
It costs me ca. 4 hours to find this. Why is this not properly documented for Windows users?

If I understand the syntax right, then it is like this for automation-tasks:
sqlite3.exe -init "[scriptname]" "[databasename]" ""

Answer (score 7):

Put `sqlite3.exe` wherever you want, as long as you remember that place and you're able to start `sqlite3` from there.

Applying a script to a database (maybe a newly-created one), in command prompt:

```
sqlite3.exe my-new-db.somesuffix < myscript.sql
```

Executing a script within interactive `sqlite3` session:

```
sqlite3.exe my-new-db.somesuffix
....
.read myscript.sql
....
```

Both variants are valid and usable at times. (Note: if your `.sql` was generated for non-sqlite database, I'd expect that it will require some changes to work in `sqlite3`. And things like stored procedures and user-defined functions will be definitely lost).

Comment: Thanks! So from cmd I get `Error: incomplete SQL:  |-`, and from  sqlite3 shell it just gives more `....>` lines when hitting enter, no message. In neither way any database file was created. Is that all I can expect for error message?

Comment: `incomplete SQL` is probably caused by syntax differences between sqlite and your source database, we can't solve it without looking at the code. As of the `....>` prompt in sqlite shell, I think you **omitted the leading dot** before `read`. It should be `.read` and not just `read`. (Why everyone asking questions feels so confident when it comes to editing commands provided in the answers?)

Comment: I'm not editing your commands, but maybe I don't use them correctly. Should I create the database before running these commands?  I don't seem to get even an empty database created, or shouldn't that happen when executing the first line you gave in sqlite3 session? Or how to create an empty database from cmd?

Comment: Database is created after a single *successful* sql statement (even a do-nothing statement like `select 1 as result` -- but then it can be a file of size 0). You can work with an existing empty database if you prefer, but it's better to start from scratch each time while you're debugging your script (otherwise you'll have to solve problems with objects already existing from previous attempts: add `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS...` before each `CREATE TABLE`, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Although the thread is years old but I have not seen anywhere the option I propose:

```
set "database=example.db"
%~dp0sqlite3.exe -cmd ".read script.sql" %database%.
```

This option after executing the script leaves open a command window with sqlite running and the database open.