# How to exit sqlite3 from bash script after initializing database

Tags: bash, sqlite

I have a folder with multiple `.sql` files, each creating their own database. I'm trying the below bash script to loop through each file and initialize the database with sqlite3.

```
for filepath in $(find ~/sql/ -name '*.sql'); do
        sqlite3 "${file}.db" -init "$filepath"
done
```

My issue is I have to manually type `.quit` in the terminal to exit sqlite3 before the bash loop continues.

I tried adding `.quit` but the terminal doesn't recognize the sqlite command. Do I need to add an exit command in the `.sql` files to exit sqlite from bash's terminal or something else?

EDIT: from the comments, I got the script to run automatically with `sqlite3 "${file}.db" < "$filepath"`.

Comment: Try adding `-batch`

Comment: I just tried ```sqlite3 -batch "${file}.db" -init "$filepath"``` and it's still needing manual ```.quit```. Is that right? I also tried adding ```.quit``` to each ```.sql``` file and got the same issue.

Comment: Why are you using `-init`?

Comment: Also, see https://sqlite.org/cli.html#using_sqlite3_in_a_shell_script

Comment: `sqlite3 "${file}.db" < "$filepath"` ?

Comment: `-init` is meant to start an interactive session.  If you don't want an interactive session, use something else, like `sqlite3 database.db ".read commands.sql"`

Comment: @jhnc thank you, that worked! The first time I tried ```<``` routing, I got "stdin is not a tty", but this time it worked.
@AnonCoward I based my script on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14789739/how-to-use-sqlite3-exe-to-create-database-from-exported-sql-script. ```-init``` doc says read/process named file, so I wasn't aware it was started an interactive session. That's helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where you can't/don't want to pass the commands in via standard input, a workaround is to misspell `.quit` (e.g., `.quoot`) as the last statement in the `-init` file, and pass the `-bail` option on the command-line.

`sqlite3` will execute commands in the `-init` file until reaching one that produces an error (hopefully the intentionally misspelled one), and then terminate with a nonzero status.  To exit solely at the end, you can insert `.bail on` into the file just prior to the misspelled command.  In either case, the bash script can then continue.